# Invalid signature while passing two terms in yelp url

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, yelp

I am trying to do a yelp query and using OAuth Lib

Here is the code

```
  NSURL *URL = [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=petrol+restaurants&ll=%f,%f&radius_filter=300",coordinate.latitude,coordinate.longitude]];

  OAConsumer *consumer = [[OAConsumer alloc] initWithKey:consumerKey secret:consumerSecret];
  OAToken *token = [[OAToken alloc] initWithKey:tokenUrl secret:tokenSecret];

  id<OASignatureProviding, NSObject> provider = [[OAHMAC_SHA1SignatureProvider alloc] init];
  NSString *realm = nil;

  OAMutableURLRequest *request = [[OAMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:URL
                                                                 consumer:consumer
                                                                    token:token
                                                                    realm:realm
                                                        signatureProvider:provider];
  [request prepare];

  NSURLConnection *connection = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest:request delegate:self];
  connection = nil;
```

The code works perfect if the query has one term , `term=petrol` e.g But if I add two terms like `term=petrol+fuel` it starts giving me error `{"error": {"text": "Signature was invalid", "id": "INVALID_SIGNATURE", "description": "Invalid signature`

What is wrong with this code?

SAMPLE API REQUEST

```
http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=cream+puffs&location=San+Francisco
```

iTS Contains a + but when i use + it gives me above error

Comment: Your code is fine, go to yelp api documentation and see there how to use multiple parameters in a single query and see if its possible or not, hope this will help you

Comment: @Talha This is a SAMple request in documentation http://api.yelp.com/v2/search?term=cream+puffs&location=San+Francisco

Comment: according to your sample request it seems to me that the request is fine when searching the exact word like Cream puffs is a food name so it is written in request as cream+puffs (+) plus sign indicate that is a single word while your word petrol+fuel is not a single word these are two different terms you can do it somehow as petrol+pumps or fuel+stations etc, hope this might help you

Comment: @Talha No its not like that Cream+Puffs gives the same error

Comment: Have yelp api documentation describe briefly about the searching terms?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I encoded the String with UTF8 Encoding and now working well

Comment: Would you be able to post an example of your working code? I cannot get mine to work at all.